# OpenNTF Import on xPages Eclipse Menu?

Tags: xpages

I attended the MWLUG conference in Pittsburgh.  One of the things I saw was an entry in the Eclipse menu, to let you import a custom control from OpenNTF.  How can I add this to my menu or does it come as a part of updates for Notes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an OpenNTF Project - Import and Export from Domino Designer http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Import%20and%20Export%20for%20Designer

It can be used to package databases for export to OpenNTF. It can be used to import not only custom controls but any design element. It's based on an XML file in the project. The file defines which design elements should be imported (there may be XPages for e.g. testing that aren't required when using the functionality).

If you're pushing anything up to OpenNTF, include the XML file of what design elements developers need to pull down from your NSF for their app to work completely.

If you want to see it in action, you should be able to use it to import the Mobile Value Picker project I put on OpenNTF. You'll see it doesn't pull in the XPages available in the sample app to demonstrate the functionality. http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Mobile%20Value%20Picker

Comment: Thanks.  How do you install it?  Page says To install this tool drag this extension.xml file and drop it onto your My Widgets sidebar panel.  But drag it from where?  from that link?  I tried that and nothing was dropped on My Widgets.

Comment: If you drag it from the "Install" link to the My Widgets panel, that should work. The other way of installing it is to go to the Project itself (the link above) and download the release. Then install into Designer, pointing it to the folder containing the site.xml (the same way you install the Extension Library into Designer)

Comment: The link on the cog wheel. You might need the embedded browser